# Will Google SQL route read request to the replica for me?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Will Google Cloud SQL route a read request to a read-replica for me when I send a query to the master's IP or do I need to add logic to the code to send read-request to the IP for the read-replica?

-Z

Comment: CloudSQL Gen1 or Gen2? Do you mean fail-over replica or read-replica?

Comment: Gen2, and read-replica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read-Replica is only designed to provide scalability and not high-availability. The idea of read-replica is to provide some sort of scaling-out by allowing reads (selects), however all writes (update/delete/insert) will need to happen on your master instance.

In case your master instance is down, you can promote the read-replica to be master but this is manual process and will not happen automatically.

If you're looking for high-availability, you will need failover-replica. The failover replica will be automatically promoted to be master and will retain original master's IP address.

Comment: So I will need to add logic in the code to switch to the read-replica IP for any select statement? Or does it all go through one IP address?

Comment: as @Herman said, with Read-Replica you need to route requests yourself to the read-replica to distribute reads.